# dotnet core 1.x authorize tag change port

Tags: redirect, asp.net-core, port, authorize-attribute

Please Help me.

situation: 
   OS : ubuntu, 
   WebServer : nginx
   DotnetCore Version : 1.0.4 
   multiple dotnetcore service : 80, 8081

I pubulished two projects with different port 80,8081.

When 8081 service needs authorize, then redirect login page without port.
ex)"xxx.xxxx.xxx/Account/Login" not "xxx.xxxx.xxx:8081/Account/Login"

Is there any way setting redirect with port?

Comment: I solved this problem.
There is no way with ip,
but It can be solved using domain.

I got free domains and apply them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. 
There is no way with ip, but It can be solved using domain. 
I got free domains and apply them.

freedomain site : http://www.dot.tk/ko/index.html

nginx site setting location : /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server {
listen 80;
    server_name www.xxxx1.tk xxxx1.tk;
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5001;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

server {
listen 80;
    server_name www.xxxx2.tk xxxx2.tk;
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5002;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```